# How to connect containers on two different hosts connected by LAN

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I would like to know how to make one container discoverable to another container running on different host but connected by LAN. Basically, I want to run two containers on different hosts and I want them to communicate, in this way I suppose I can implemented distributed training on tensorflow.

Is there any possible way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple options to do that:

- You can use [weave](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/install/using-weave/).
- You can set up a [docker overlay network](https://gist.github.com/bbl/ed1f1a0e0597e537e20f28d78c1a0d45)
- You can use [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/)
- You can create `macvlan` [docker network](https://gist.github.com/bbl/dad5ea94cdf8f384bb7a47dd4869b2eb)

You may also use a special script called [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework), which will automatically do the job:

- Assign [static macvlan ip](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#connect-a-container-to-a-local-physical-interface)
- Assign dynamic ip, using [DHCP client](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#dhcp)